# How can I mock a static function with phpunit 4.6.6 and later

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I know staticExpects is deprecated as of PHPUnit 3.8 and will be removed completely with later versions.
But in our project, using static function everywhere.So,It's a big problem to make phpunit.And In our dev,phpunit version is 4.6.6,I can not back to 3.8.
My question is how can I do like staticExpects?
code:

```
class A {
    public static function staticfun(){
       //dosomething....     
    }
}
class B {
    public static function callA(){
       A::staticfun();
    }

}

class TestA extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{
    public function test(){
        //I want to mock staticfun()
        B::callA();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you'd need to use an extension like [uopz](http://php.net/uopz) that allows you to redefine functions and methods at runtime.

In your test class you'd add something like:

```
public static function setupBeforeClass()
{
    uopz_backup("A", "staticfun");
    uopz_function("A", "staticfun", function () {
        // do something else
    });
}

public static function tearDownAfterClass()
{
    uopz_restore("A", "staticfun");
}
```

This'll:

- back up the original method
- redefine it as the given closure
- restore the original when the tests in the class are complete

Comment: @Paul : now that the *uopz_backup* etc.. functions are deprecated from PECL uopz 5.0.0 , what is the alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can, in a general case, not mock static function calls. Don't use static calls if you intend to test your software with mocks. You can try and fiddle with evil tricks, but this usually is a huge pain.

You probably didn't read the documentation for the staticExpects feature of PHPUnit thoroughly. It does not do what you need. Sebastian implemented that feature in PHPUnit 3.5, but it didn't work as he was intending, because people didn't understand its limitations. So it was removed again in 3.8.

Face the fact that you created untestable software by using static calls. Start to throw them out and improve the testability of the software that way. It is painful and will cost time, but it is the only way.

Comment: The age of a project does not change the fact that static methods cannot be mocked. You can still call them and check the return value. You can also try to wrap them in instantiated objects that simply forward the call to the static function. THAT object may then be mocked. It will be a long way to fix it, but if the project is old and untestable, either don't touch it, or accept that changing it will create bugs that cannot be tested.